# freemarker.template.TemplateException: Error reading included file start_script.ftl

Tags: freemarker

My application running in tomcat 6. I have integrated freemarker template with Spring MVC.

```
I have "abct.ftl" under "freemarker/pages" and "xyz.ftl" under "freemarker/pages 
/formal". I am including "abc.ftl" in "xyz.ftl" using "<#include  
"../abc.ftl"/>".

This is working fine on MACH and LINUX but its giving below error on windows 7. I did search 
for this error in google and tried many things but nothing helped fixing this issue.

The exception stack trace is given below:

freemarker.template.TemplateException: Error reading included file abc.ftl
        at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:167)  
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template abc.ftl not found.

Please help me fixing this issue.

Thanks
```

Comment: It's rather strange that it happens on Window only. Can it include a template from the same directory at all?

Comment: yes it is able to load templates from same directory on the home page. but there are multiple buttons on the home page. When I click one  of those buttons and try to open a new page, it tries to load template with other nested/included template. Thats the time when it gives the error.

Comment: It should be clear that the URL of the page visiting is irrelevant when it comes to `#include`. Only the path of the templates on the server side matters. So, my question meant to be, can you `#include` another `.ftl` that is in the same directory on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me on this issue.
I have found the solution to this problem so wanted to share it with you guys.

I went through the following documentation on freemarker site and found the solution:

[http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#autoid_41[freemarker.org]](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#autoid_41%5Bfreemarker.org%5D)

As suggested in this documentation, I replaced `<#include "../abc.ftl"/>` with `<#include "/pages/abc.ftl"/>.`

Freemarker documentation says, “FreeMarker always normalizes the paths before passing them to the template loader, so the paths do not contain/../ and such, and are relative to the imaginary template root directory.”

The template root directory is the one that we specify in templateLoaderPath:

`property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/freemarker"`

I tested this fix on Windows, Linux, Mach and its working everywhere.